# Opposite of "summary"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is the opposite of *summary* as in a *Summary Report* or *A Summary*? Common suggestions are *Exposition* but that doesn't seem right at all, and other suggestions I find in a search are just antonyms of *short* like *long* and *lengthy*. *Summary* stands on its own as a noun, but none of the others do except *Exposition* which seems very different in meaning.

In my specific case I have two reports; one is titled *End of Month Summary Report* and one is *End of Month Report - Long Version* which is painfully awkward. I'd like to keep the titles short and *End of Month Summary* sounds perfect. I need a concise, understandable phrase for the latter.

Comment: What is wrong with *End of Month Report*? It's the whole report, nothing more. The *End of Month Summary*, *End of Month Report (Summary)*, or *End of Month Summary Report* is then a summary of that report.

Comment: Or *End of Month Exegesis*  if you want to use a higher-priced word.  An [exegesis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exegesis) is "An exposition or explanation of a text".

Comment: @Jim Well there's two end of month reports! One is a summary but it is still a report all the same, therefore neither one is the only End of Month Report.

Comment: @jwpat7 unfortunately I doubt our AP department knows the word Exegesis! I'm a fan of UX first and a fan of fancy specific words second =p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At work I generated a report system with two buttons on the main screen: "Summary Reports" and "Detailed Reports". Does "Detail" or "Detailed" work for you? Can you give an example sentence where you'd like to use this word?

---

For reports, I have sometimes seen terms like "High-level" for "Summary" and "Low-level" for "Detailed" interchangeably.

Comment: It's a report system as well; updated my question to be specific. We have a End of Month summary report which groups items very liberally and a "long version report" which has every record detailed explicitly. The title of the reports were End of Month Summary and End of Month Report Long Version; I'd like to keep the titles as short and clear as possible. Detail seems quite fitting.

Comment: +1 *Summary/Detail* are the normal words used in the context of reports. In speech, I often hear *breakdown*, but you won't often see this on screen as an alternative type of report that you can request.

Comment: I was going to answer that the opposite of the summary is the actual report, but then I saw this. +1

Answer (score 9):

[*Elaboration*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/elaborate_2?q=elaboration) is the opposite of *summary*.

Answer (score 3):

I actually like *analysis* for this purpose -- it suggests that the report contains more than just results but also the raw data and reasoning that lead to them. *Detailed* is also good.

Answer (score 3):

*Comprehensive End of Month Report* may be appropriate in your context.

Answer (score 3):

In the British government department in which I once worked, reports were divided into Summary and Detail.